# New instance of an object is actually reusing an existing object

Tags: c#, unit-testing, object, constructor

I'm setting up unit tests of a custom class in VS2015. I noticed something that seemed odd when running two test methods on the same class. Here's a simplification of the problem:

```
public MyClass
{
    private List<string> _MyList = new List<string>();
    public void AddItem(string s)
    {
        _MyList.Add(s);
    }
    public List<string> GetList()
    {
        return _MyList;
    }
}

[TestMethod]
public void AddSingleItem()
{
    MyClass instance = new MyClass();
    instance.AddItem("string 1");
    Assert.AreEqual(1, instance.GetList().Count);
}

[TestMethod]
public void AddMultipleItems()
{
    MyClass instance = new MyClass();
    instance.AddItem("string 1");
    instance.AddItem("string 2");
    Assert.AreEqual(2, instance.GetList().Count);
}
```

The problem is that the first test passes fine, and the second test passes fine when run on its own, but if run together the second test will fail saying the assert expected and actual are different, as if the methods were adding strings to the same object (despite having created a new instance of it).

I added a constructor to the class which ensures `_MyList` gets cleared when it's instantiated, which solved the problem, but I want to understand if this is to be expected and why? Is it standard practice to have to make your default constructors clear all your properties like that? It seems odd that `new MyClass()` doesn't actually generate a totally new instance.

For reference, here's the constructor I mentioned:

```
public MyClass()
{
    _MyList.Clear();
}
```

Comment: Does the code you've posted exhibit the behavior you're talking about, or did you simplify it and then not run the tests?

Comment: I didn't test this code exactly but it contains all the parts involved in the unit tests. I'll mock it up quickly just to be sure it's reproducible with this code.

Comment: Please read [MCVE] guidance one more time. There is no point to post some code that has no relation to problem you have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no reason to get the behavior you're describing with the code you've posted. I'm guessing that in your simplification of the problem you changed something crucial. Most likely it's that your private field:

```
private List<string> _MyList = new List<string>();
```

is probably static:

```
private static List<string> _MyList = new List<string>();
```

This would cause each instance of your class to reuse the same instance. Adding a constructor that resets this value would give the appearance of fixing the problem, but it would cause more problems down the road because the first instance you create would have its list reset every time a new instance is created. You'd likely start seeing weird race conditions that are hard to track down, and so on.

If this is the case, ensuring that the field is not `static` should fix things.

Comment: Derp. Exact problem. I'll accept as soon as the timer allows.